# Need a javascript library for free drawing on canvas

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, drawing

I'm planning to make a fairly simple drawing app in the browser. I'm looking for a Javascript library that:

- Has a permissive license (MIT or BSD, GPL is *okay* but not preferred)
- Makes it simple to draw on the canvas, for example something like this:

  ```
  canvas.init($("#my_canvas"), {"mode": "drawing"});
  ```
- Supports touch out of the box (bonus points for multitouch/zoom)
- Bonus points for doing it in a vector-style format
- Getting the paths/points from the canvas should be possible/easy

I've found a couple that look promising ([EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS), [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/)), but I haven't investigated too deeply yet. For an existing example of the kind of thing I'm interested in, [Xournal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xournal) is a desktop version, though I'm also rather interested in the idea of infinite canvas (see [MyPaint](http://mypaint.intilinux.com/), though it's raster-only).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few libraries that fit your criteria of search.

#### Pixi.js

Pixi is a Canvas rendering interface, which in my opinion is FAR better than other rendering engines.

Features:

- MIT Licensed
- Multi-touch interactivity
- Full scene graph
- Multi-platform
- Sprite Sheet Support
- Renderer auto-detect
- Text support

Resources:

- [Website](http://www.pixijs.com/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/)
- [Documentations](http://www.pixijs.com/resources/)
- [Examples](http://www.pixijs.com/examples/)

#### Phaser:

**MIT Licensed**
Though Phaser is essentially a Game Framework it can most well be used for building Interactive applications like Paint. It uses Pixi.js as it's canvas interface. And has much more capabilities than Pixi, eg. has a Button class to build just buttons.

Links

- [Website](http://phaser.io/)
- [Github](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser)
- [Documentations](http://docs.phaser.io/)
- [Examples](http://examples.phaser.io/)

Comment: IT or MIT license?

Comment: Sorry about that it's "MIT".